# Remove version number from reference (avoiding "Could not load file or assembly..." error)?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5

In my class library, I am referencing DLL's from my website's bin folder. Sometimes the DLL's in the bin folders get updated, then I get the error of:

```
    Could not load file or assembly 'MyAssembly.Sub, Version=3.7.2096.3, Culture=neutral,
 PublicKeyToken=dfeaee3f6978ac79' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's
 manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.
(Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

How do I disregard the version number so that the DLL's can get updated without the application looking for a specific version number?? Can't just look for the namespace only?

This is what the reference looks like in my .csproj file:

```
<Reference Include="MyAssembly.Sub, Version=3.7.2057.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=dfeaee3f6978ac79, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>..\..\SomeWebsite\bin\MyAssembly.Sub.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>False</Private>
</Reference>
```

Comment: Just don't update the [AssemblyVersion] :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an [assembly binding redirection specified in `web.config`](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CDEQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.devx.com%2Ftips%2FTip%2F35310&ei=JoF-TNW7Ds2K4Ab-z_mGBg&usg=AFQjCNHijlgTCczv3hxW4BavqLLw9GwYRA&sig2=KsUdaT1aF3rhrQHemSGiiA). I'm not sure whether you can say "always use latest", but you can specify a particular version. When you update the version you're deploying, just update web.config as well.

For more on assembly binding redirection, read the [MSDN article about it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2fc472t2.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

It's actually easier to set specific version property to false.

Comment: That sounds interesting. Since his was already set to False, do you mean that simply deleting the following would work? 
", Version=3.7.2057.3"

Answer (score 1):

Unsure what you mean but there is [assembly redirection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I take as this is a problem that occurs during development. The assembly in the bin folder gets updated as a result of some development activity.

You are using strongly named assemblies during development. A reference to a strongly named assembly only works when the reference specifies the exact version of the assembly.

Perhaps you'd better not sign assemblies while developing and debugging. Referencing an assembly that is not strongly named is much simpler. I believe that a matching filename is sufficient.

In the production environment, strong names are definitely a good idea though.